# Repository Version Policy : ignore missing poms?

Tags: maven, nexus

Having looked at this some more I realise

The thing that confuses me is that maven is searching the repo for this file and not finding it. I don’t understand why a different local repo (one of 6 listed repos in the POM file) should be a problem.

My assumption is that the problem comes in the Version Policy of the repository being Release. This is surely what the error implies but the old repository also had a policy of release and anyway I’m not storing the snapshot on there is is only looking for it as it is the dependency of a dependency stored on Maven Central that isn’t found.

Is there a way I can either change the policy to allow it to be searched for snapshots or stop maven from searching this repo for snapshots ?

---

We have moved our internal repo from on server to another and upgraded it to 3.12.1-01 from  2.14.9-01.

We have migrated the artifacts over using the agent.  I have built a couple of simple projects using the new repo and all seems well.

However on one app I am getting this error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://reposerver:8081/repository/releases/org/glassfish/javax.el/3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT/javax.el-3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT.pom

Downloading: http://reposerver:8081/repository/releases/org/glassfish/javax.el/3.0.1-b07-SNAPSHOT/javax.el-3.0.1-b07-SNAPSHOT.pom

Downloading: http://reposerver:8081/repository/releases/org/glassfish/javax.el/3.0.1-b08-SNAPSHOT/javax.el-3.0.1-b08-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

...

```
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project : 
Could not resolve dependencies for project : 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-
jsp:jar:9.2.19.v20160908 -> org.glassfish.web:javax.servlet.jsp:jar:2.3.2 -> 
org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT: 

Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish:javax.el:pom:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT from/to releases.new 
(http://reposerver:8081/repository/releases/): Failed to transfer file:
 http://reposerver:8081/repository/releases/org/glassfish/javax.el/3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT/javax.el-3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT.pom. 

Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Repository version policy: RELEASE does 
not allow version: 3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT. -> [Help 1]
```

If I point back to the old repo I don't have a problem at all.  I had a quick go trying to change jetty versions and exclude javax.el to just avoid using the snapshot dependency and get the project to build but I can't seem to easily do this without causing catastrophic build failures.

Checking again I have missed this ongoing warning when using the old repositorty

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b07-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b08-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

I have tried adding this repo which seems to have the snapshot

```
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
```

but this makes no difference.

As I understand it maven is trying all repos to recursively find all dependencies and as my local repo is last it is reporting the error after checking my local repo.  The error about snapshot policies is a false message and the issue is it can't find the POM for the javax-el jar and so can't continue looking for dependencies.  I don't understand why it iognores after looking at one repo and fails when it is instructed to look at another ?

The only difference between success an failure at my end is

**Success:**

```
 <repository>
     <id>releases</id>
     <name>App Repository</name>
     <url>http://oldserver:8081/repository/releases/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>App Repository</name>
        <url>http://newserver:8081/repository/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

**FAILURE**

```
    <repository>
         <id>releases</id>
         <name>App Repository</name>
         <url>http://newserver:8081/repository/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>App Repository</name>
            <url>http://newserver:8081/repository/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

Is this a setting on the new nexus repository ?  At the moment I'm hoping for a simple like for like fix but if you think I need to change the dependencies I'm calling then that's fine

Jetty dependencies called

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jstl</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.19.v20160908</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.19.v20160908</version>     
</dependency>
```

Comment: The point is you have referenced SNAPSHOT versions in your poms and that's what the errors show....in Central there are no SNAPSHOT's available...

Comment: Really?  How would i know 9.2.19.v20160908 is a snapshot version ?  Should I be sticking to simple numbers ?  they all seem to be RC which is release candidate no ?

Comment: I haven't written about org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b06-SNAPSHOT ...

Comment: okay thanks.  I see your point. The odd thing is the snapshot is a sub dependency from jetty-jsp (9.2.19.v20160908).  I suspect I'm missing something or there would be more on this and I'm surprised it's included in a standard release.

Comment: I would suggest to analyse your dependency tree via `mvn dependency:tree` and see where those `-SNAPSHOT` parts are coming from...

Answer (score 5):

Okay I haven't found an answer for why the versions of Nexus seem to act differently (this my be my misunderstanding of the root cause!)

I have fixed it with a simple pom mod (which I thought I had tried before but I must have gone round in some silly circles)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.19.v20160908</version>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                 <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                 <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>       
    </dependency>

     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.el -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Sadly this took me a a few hours so I thought I'd leave this here as an answer just in case.  I'm really not trying to squeeze another 2 points & if you think I should delete the question please just comment here and I'll happily delete.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to answer one's own question. And it helped me since I was having the same error message (not from a Jetty dependency, but from a Hive one). So have an upvote!